# Many to mapping using hibernate annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have 3 tables in my database.

Schema i have developed here.

One employee can attend multiple meetings and one meeting can be attained by multiple employees.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/653a40

I am using hibernate in my application.

This are my pojos.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="emp")
public class Employee
{
@Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="Name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="salary")
    private String salary;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="emp_meeting", 
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")}, 
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="meetingId")})
private Set<MEETING> meetings= new HashSet<MEETING>();


   // getter and setter
}



@Entity
@Table(name="MEETING")
public class MEETING{


    @Id
    @Column(name="meetingId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int mid;

    @Column(name="agenda")
    private String agenda;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="meetings")
    private Set<Employee> emps= new HashSet<Employee>();

    //gettter and setter
}
```

Is this correct?
Because I dont know how to insert into 3rd table ?

Comment: what is the 3rd table anyways?

Comment: Please check my db schema on sqlfiddle .Link is in the question

Answer (score 0):

As you association table has no more information than the two foreign key of your main tables, the insertion in this table is managed by hibernate when you associate your objects `Employee`  and `MEETING`.  So to me your mapping is correct, if you encounter problems, don't forget to associate in both direction (that is, in java, if you are adding an employee to a meeting, you should add the meeting to this employee and vice-versa)

(On another topic : your class name should respect java convention naming and be `Meeting` instead of `MEETING`).

Comment: But how will i get the  value of response column . I have not linked it in amy of my pojo.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to insert explicitly in the third table. Any save/persist call with Employee having the Set of meetings populated will result in auto save in the mapping table as you are working with Cascade.ALL cascade level.